# How can I merge cleanly & easily between related git repositories?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

We have two related git repositories: The main repository and the external repository. 
The main repository is used within my company and contains everything. The external repository is shared with  select external parties. It has some sensitive directories excluded and slight differences in the build files.

Here's the requirements:

- Both repositories have changes that need to be periodically be merged
  together (e.g. we want merge between the two repos in both
  directions).
- The sensitive directories must never get merged into
  the external repo, and merging from the external repo to the main
  repo must not delete the sensitive directories.
- I would like keep the all the commit messages when merging. Currently, we occasionally copy files between repos, which usually means a useless commit message and a single commit in the destination repo that includes many commits from the source repo.
- I don't care too much about the current history of the external repository. It don't need to be kept when I set up a better way to manage these repositories.
- It's ok if internal developers need to run extra commands when setting this up or before merging, but I'd like to be able to write scripts that run these commands to make it easier.

Comment: One idea that I had was to use `git filter-branch` in the main repo to make an external branch that had the sensitive directories removed. The external branch would be pushed to the external repo (by adding it as a git remote). The hope was that I would then be able to merge from the main master branch to the external branch, since they have common commits. However, I realized that although I viewed both branches as having the same set  of commits, `git filter-branch` changed the commits in the external branch, so git doesn't see any common commits between the master and external branches.

Comment: Just checking, would it be off the table to make a more drastic change in your workflow, like having the sensitive directories in one repository and the externally exposed ones in a different repository? Possibly one being a submodule of the other?

Comment: yeah, That's worth considering. I was told that we used submodules in the past (I'm not sure if it was for this situation) and they didn't work well. I think the issue was that everyone had to change their workflow to keep the submodules updated. Ideally, we wouldn't have to do anything differently except when merging between repos.

Comment: Also, how would submodules work with only internal people having acccess to the repo used as the submodule? Could you have another branch use a different repo for the submodule?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think some submodule information possibly including the URL of the repo is stored in the config file for the repository, so it has to be the same for every branch, but don't take my word for it. But perhaps external developers who don't have access to the sensitive code could simply not initialize that submodule. Just throwing out some ideas.